# Is it possible to change/override the ModelState error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Im using a CMS and using the templates provided i have everything working as i intend. For this example lets say a user is attempting to login using a username and password.

One of the issues i am facing is when a certain condition hits it returns an obscure error message which makes no sense.

So in this scenario, user logs in and after 3 attempts, locks themselves out. The error returned is `"locked!"` which doesnt look good.

The HTML of the template supplied to report the error message is (ive left the rest out but can supply if required) in a csHtml form

```
 @using (Html.BeginOurForm<OurLoginController>("HandleLogin", new {URL = model.Url}))
  {
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
  }
```

I then looked at the Controller the HTML form is calling and its a generic declaration i.e.

```
public class OurLoginController : OurController
{
}
```

I see the error listed in the method in this class but i cant change the class as its a third party component.

Is there any other way to change the error message to something friendly? There are other conditions that are checked in the class/method too.

Comment: and where is the code of the template you want to change?

Comment: @LeandroBardelli its in a View

Comment: Why don't change the view?

Comment: I guess thats what i may be asking indirectly. So the code above (HTML) is what outputs the error message. I dont know if theres another way to output the error and change it as it does that for a couple of controls on the page?

Comment: Sorry for not understand you. So but the code of the CMS is open source? You can change it? or is a compiled dll? If not maybe you can change it with javascript at interface level.

Comment: Its a compiled dll i believe.... Im not sure about javascript at interface level. Any pointers?